# Add row number within PostgreSQL COPY command

Tags: postgresql

When I'm running a `COPY my_table FROM 'my_table_source.csv' WITH HEADER CSV;` is it possible to extract the row number within the csv file and add that information into my target table? I have some flat files coming from external sources and going to multiple databases that would be useful to trace backwards during occasional audits done down the road. Thanks.

Comment: By row number do you mean the line number in the file? In other words it is not actually a number in the row just the position in the file?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, yes. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: Add column names and omit the name of the serial?

Comment: @nclu. Then the only way I can think to do this is use the `PROGRAM` feature of `COPY` and run the file through a program that adds a row number to each line. That would necessitate also adding a field to the table. This would be a variation of idea from @wildplasser which uses a `SERIAL` type field. In either case I'm not sure how reliable this is. It would take just one change in the file to unlink the relationship. Seems better to have some set of fields per that constitute a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Add column names and omit the name of the serial:

---

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE passwords (
        seq serial not null PRIMARY KEY
        , name text
        , passwd text
        , uid integer not null
        , gid integer not null
        , gcos text
        , home text
        , shell text
        );
COPY passwords(name,passwd,uid,gid,gcos,home,shell)
FROM '/etc/passwd' WITH csv DELIMITER ':' ;

SELECT * FROM passwords
WHERE seq < 10
        ;
```

---

Output:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
COPY 48
 seq |  name  | passwd | uid |  gid  |  gcos  |      home      |       shell       
-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+--------+----------------+-------------------
   1 | root   | x      |   0 |     0 | root   | /root          | /bin/bash
   2 | daemon | x      |   1 |     1 | daemon | /usr/sbin      | /usr/sbin/nologin
   3 | bin    | x      |   2 |     2 | bin    | /bin           | /usr/sbin/nologin
   4 | sys    | x      |   3 |     3 | sys    | /dev           | /usr/sbin/nologin
   5 | sync   | x      |   4 | 65534 | sync   | /bin           | /bin/sync
   6 | games  | x      |   5 |    60 | games  | /usr/games     | /usr/sbin/nologin
   7 | man    | x      |   6 |    12 | man    | /var/cache/man | /usr/sbin/nologin
   8 | lp     | x      |   7 |     7 | lp     | /var/spool/lpd | /usr/sbin/nologin
   9 | mail   | x      |   8 |     8 | mail   | /var/mail      | /usr/sbin/nologin
(9 rows)
```

Comment: The [documentation on the serial type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) says "Because ... serial ... are implemented using sequences, there may be ... gaps in the sequence of values ..., even if no rows are ever deleted." Hence, this behavior does not seem to be guaranteed (even though I never saw a deviation). Is there a way to be sure that the row numbers are gapless?

Comment: Short answer: no. If you want a gapless enumeration, you could use `row_number() over (ORDER BY seq) AS rn`

Comment: Seems you're right. :-) Another quote of the fine [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createsequence.html): "Because `nextval` and `setval` calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently."

Comment: ... and using the less expensive `row_number()` seems sound since "with a `cache` setting of one it is safe to assume that `nextval` values are generated sequentially" (referring to the `cache` option of the implicit `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement).